# 2 system linked together with Active Directory

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory

Today we have a web system in .net where users login and autheticates against our DB.
We got a customer that want to use Active Directory to automatic login to our system. They will use there windows logins to authenticate against our system.

Is that possible to intergrade on an easy way? And are there any modern tools for doing that job with c#?

In web.config we today have Forms login

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".LoginForm" loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx" defaultUrl="StartPage.aspx" timeout="10080" domain=""/>
     </authentication>
<authorization>
```

Is it possible to have a Windows authentication aswell? Do I need another loginpage for windows authentication?

Is this the way it gonna be? Or are there any "best practice" when you need both form and windows login?

Is it important for they to open up any port on firewall, or are there other important settings on the IIS to let the traffic true?

Or do you have any other suggestions or tips to think about?

Edit: our customer have som user data from the AD that we will work with in our system. So not only the login we will need to have some data aswell. Is all this possible?

Comment: How will the end user authenticate to your application? will he provide his domain account name and password? or will the windows domain account of the internet explorer be used? in other words single sign on?

Comment: They will use the username from their windows login. That's the user. And in my world (correct me if im wrong) they will go to my page and automatic login true windows authenticate and IIS. They will run the server with my internet app at theirs place. So it shouldn't be any security risk. That shouldn't be any problem? Never worked with AD before. ;)

Comment: How does the user log on to the database that your system uses? will that be Windows authentication too? What kind of DB server is it? SQL server?

Is the database server located on the same machine as the IIS?

Comment: Today we have a session. Yes it's SQL server. The database will not be located on the the same machine as the IIS but it will be located on the same network.

Comment: And how does your web app. connect to the SQL server? using SQL server user name and password? or using the windows domain account of the browser user?

Comment: OK then Windows provides everything for you, you only need to configure the browser, IIS and SQL server to support the delegation of windows credentials, if all computers are in one domain and the windows server is 2003 and higher then everthing should work out of the box, just make sure that the URL of you web app. is part of the IE intranet zone

Comment: Yes today it validates against the SQL server. But now we will control if the user is authenticated with the windows domain account of the browser user as you saying. We will check if that username exist in DB and in the AD then if it's true then he will get authenticated on the web app.

Comment: Sorry, removed my comment. The user is getting commited to use IE? Do you have any good tutorial or guide of all configuration?

Comment: YOu don't need to validate the user agains the AD, this is already done between the IE and IIS, check this:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

Inside your web app. you simply get the windows user name and validate it against your database.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Perhaps I need to have a look in their AD because they have some levels that they explained like this.In the AD they maybe have Admin.219.James, User.219.Ray and like that. And I think that "219" aint in their name and I need to see that nr. So maybe as I said I need to look in the AD.